# Rellenar Agrupaciones específicas con valores cercanos en pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero rellenar algunos vacíos con valores cercanos pero que estén en una clase específica:

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso el precio para galletas en el mes de Agosto no está, pero está en el mes de Julio, así que quiero que tome ese valor, igualmente para todos los demás, en el caso del pan, sólo existen valores posteriores, quiero que se rellene con los valores de Abril en este caso que es el más cercano, de tal forma que quede así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté hacer esto, pero me salen varios errores,

```html
df['Precio']=df.groupby(by=['Artículo'])['Precio'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ¡Buen dia!

Su código no estaba tan lejos de la solución el toque mágico lo otorga la función *[bfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html)* el cual se usa para completar hacia atrás los valores faltantes **NaN** en el conjunto de datos.

Reescribí su dataframe y poniendo en marcha la solución así:

```
import pandas as pd

columnas = ["Articulo", "Mes", "Precio"]
datos = [
        ["Galletas","Junio",500],["Galletas","Julio",650],
        ["Galletas","Agosto",],["Papas","Enero",550],
        ["Papas","Febrero",],["Aceite","Enero",900],
        ["Aceite","Febrero",],["Pan","Enero",],
        ["Pan","Febrero",],["Pan","Marzo",],
        ["Pan","Abril",800],["Pan","Mayo",700]
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(datos,columns=columnas)
df['Precio']=df.groupby(by=['Articulo'])['Precio'].ffill().bfill()

print(df)
```

la manera en que hace el llamado a *ffill con fillna* se puede simplificar y añadiendo bfill() obtenemos como resultado el siguiente DataFrame:

```
    Articulo      Mes  Precio
0   Galletas    Junio   500.0
1   Galletas    Julio   650.0
2   Galletas   Agosto   650.0
3      Papas    Enero   550.0
4      Papas  Febrero   550.0
5     Aceite    Enero   900.0
6     Aceite  Febrero   900.0
7        Pan    Enero   800.0
8        Pan  Febrero   800.0
9        Pan    Marzo   800.0
10       Pan    Abril   800.0
11       Pan     Mayo   700.0
```

### Nota adicional:

1. Cuando declare variables no utilice tildes como lo esta haciendo
   para el nombre de columna `"Artículos"` puede profundizar sobre como llevar buenas practicas en [Style Guide for Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)
2. A la hora de pedir ayuda, traté de anexar el dataframe en forma de
   texo y no de imagen puesto que asi evitamos la transcripcion de los
   datos [¿Como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)